# Dumb bell pullover muscles

Tags: exercise, muscle, shoulders, chest

I am doing dumb bell pullover as shown in [excercise](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/DBPullover.html)

Except that i lie down completly on bench, when I bring DB up i kinda feel twitch around my delts , is it normal , does shoulder also involve in this one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, deltoids are involved in the exercise.  As far as a “twitch”, you should not feel any pain or discomfort performing the exercise.  If the “twitch” persists, seek medical help, or, try a different chest exercise.  The link you provided for that exercise lists all the potentially affected body parts.  You'll see that Deltoid is listed.  And, the position of your body on the bench is not important if you follow proper form

Comment: No pain . Just twich that too on my weaker arm. It's like muscles crossing over or something